# Distributing Webpage Widgets that need to Access an Authorized API

Tags: api, authorization, client

I have developed an API that uses JWT to authorize client requests. Seasoned developers can get a JWT using a login API over HTTPS and use that JWT to make subsequent authorized API calls. That all works fine.

Now I've got some interest from less-seasoned developers who are primarily front-end oriented (HTML/CSS/Javascript developers). Ideally for this class of individual, they'd like to be instructed to "drop this script tag in your HTML, set it up like this, and magic will ensue."

Without having them also deploy some kind of proxy server on some random port (e.g. like 9090) on their back-end (which is the where my brain went when I thought about this independently), is there a canonical strategy that would allow this sort of thing without that developer having to put their JWT in their client side code, and therefore break the authorization / authentication model of the API (since in that case anyone could masquerade as that user by, e.g., simply looking at Chrome developer tools network and/or source tabs).

Obviously my back-end proxy concept is not perfect, and could be abused, but at least I could revoke a maliciously behaving JWT under some kind of abuse scenario and communicate to the affected authorized developer to come up with a resolution. Setting up a proxy service is a lot of effort for some people though. I guess I could ultimately set one up for each developer who wants this sort of thing if they were willing to pay for it, but I am left wondering "is there a better way?". What say you?

Comment: Am I correct that by JWT you mean JSON Web Tokens? https://jwt.io/

Comment: I'm not sure how the proxy server would help. Malicious users could talk to the proxy server pretending to be the widget, and the proxy would talk to the API on their behalf. Seems like the same problem as publishing the token. What am I missing?

Comment: @sbleon yes I meant JSON Web Tokens. A proxy token could at least hide the JWT from a client is all I was thinking, and I could bind the JWT for example to the static IP address of the proxy server, so it would only be accepted from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can prevent malicious users from accessing any API endpoints that the widget can access, unless you have them authenticate themselves in the widget before they can use it.

Assuming authentication is a no-go, maybe the Principle of Least Privilege is the answer. It's hard to say without knowing how interactive the widget is, but some examples:

- If the widget doesn't need write access, give it read-only access.
- Give the widget access to only the data/endpoints it needs.
- If the widget is only displaying digested data (e.g. fetching raw data but rendering a chart), have the API digest the data first instead of sending the raw data to the client (e.g. render the chart on the server). This would make the raw data more difficult to retrieve.

Comment: Yea that's basically what I expected to hear. That last bullet is a really good suggestion, thanks!